# How to auto fold html tags?

Tags: filetype-html

I am new to vim.

I have a HTML code with lots of `<li></li>` with its content that could span multiply lines like below:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        text
        text
    </li>
    <li>
        text
        text
    </li>
</ol>
```

When I apply `:set foldmethod=syntax`, vim does nothing on folding that tags.
When I apply `:set foldmethod=indent`, vim apply code folding like this:

```
<ol>
    <li>
+---- 2 lines: text------
    </li>
    <li>
+---- 2 lines: text------
    </li>
</ol>
```

However, I intend to fold the code like when I use manual folding `zfat`:

```
<ol>
+---- 4 lines: <li>------
+---- 4 lines: <li>------
</ol>
```

So that it is more condensed and, at the same time, I know it is a listed items.

The problem is: how do I achieve this with auto folding?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using foldexpression. The best would be to create a function, that analyzes each line and returns an actual foldlevel. Here is a short example, that should get you started:

```
set fen fdm=expr fde=getline(v:lnum)=~#'<[^>]*>'?'a1':getline(v:lnum)=~#'</[^>]*>'?'s1':'='
```

Read the details at `:h fold-expr` (especially the special meaning of the return values for the evaluation of the expression.